# Issues with using Gson to pretty-print JSON String

Tags: java, json, gson

Could someone please suggest why this is happening...

I’ve got some code to pretty print some JSON. To do this, I am making use out of the [Gson library](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

However, while thus usually works well, some characters don’t seem to be displayed properly. Here is a simple piece of code that demonstrates the problem:

```
//Creating the JSON object, and getting as String:
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
JsonObject inner = new JsonObject();
inner.addProperty("value", "xpath('hello')");
json.add("root", inner);
System.out.println(json.toString());

//Trying to pretify JSON String:
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement je = parser.parse(json.toString());
System.out.println(gson.toJson(je));
```

The output of the above code is:

```
{"root":{"value":"xpath('hello')"}}
{
  "root": {
    "value": "xpath(\u0027hello\u0027)"
  }
}
```

How could I fix the above?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use this code, to create `Gson` object:

```
Gson gs = new GsonBuilder()
    .setPrettyPrinting()
    .disableHtmlEscaping()
    .create();
```

The `disableHtmlEscaping()` method *tells* `gson` not to escape HTML characters such as `<`, `>`, `&`, `=`, and a single quote which caused you trouble: `'`.

Note, that this may cause trouble, if you render such unescaped JSON into a `<script/> tag` in HTML page without using additional `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` tag.

You can see how it works, and what other chars are escaped, by looking into the code of [`JsonWriter` class](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.java).